# Nuclide IDE & Remote Server Setup with Watchman

Tags: hhvm, hacklang, watchman, nuclide-editor

Facebook recently announced [Nuclide](http://nuclide.io/), that supports Remote Development and Hack.

I have followed all the installation instructions, but `autocomplete/inline error report/click-to-definition` features do not work, whereas `nuclide-language-hack, nuclide-file-tree/nuclide-remote-projects` work as expected (and `nuclide-server` from the server part / `.hhconfig` file is included on project root ).

I have installed them all except `flow` by filtering the results of `nuclide-`.

Are these features unsupported in remote access, or i have made something wrong in installation (which is pretty straightforward i think) ?

Moreover, i do not understand how [watchman](https://facebook.github.io/watchman/) is configured to work properly . I have installed it using the following commands (server runs Linux, i have also installed `inotify-tools`)

```
$ git clone https://github.com/facebook/watchman.git
$ cd watchman
$ ./autogen.sh
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install
```

and i used the following to watch my project

```
$ watchman watch /my/project/root
```

and watcher seems to be established fine.

However Nuclide reports:

> Watcher failed to start - watcher features disabled!
>
> Details: socket hang up

I am sorry that i ask installation advices here, but i do not think the above should be asked on Github either.

Thanks!

---

*Solution*: As MostafaEweda suggested, i tried to compile from source. `apm` or package installation through atom settings, did not work for me. `nuclide-installer` did not install anything at all, and installing by hand `nuclide-*` packages did not work either.

For `Windows Users` : Python3.4 throws some runtime errors (although documentation says Python 2.6 or later is supported). I used Python2.7 and these errors seem to go away.

Tip : When you install nuclide, you have to wait some minutes and atom will become unresponsive. Be patient!

Comment: If you suspect an issue with watchman, it's worth running through http://facebook.github.io/watchman/docs/troubleshooting.html.  In particular, looking at and sharing information from your logs will be helpful to diagnose and suggest a resolution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that Nuclide's [WatchmanClient](https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/blob/master/pkg/nuclide/watchman-helpers/lib/WatchmanClient.js) can't connect to your installed watchman for some reason.

Note that the tests for `WatchmanClient` is currently disabled, but maybe it will show some useful error when you remove the `x` from line 20 of [WatchmanClient-spec.js](https://github.com/facebook/nuclide/blob/master/pkg/nuclide/watchman-helpers/spec/WatchmanClient-spec.js#L20) and run: `npm test` in the `watchman-helpers` directory or add some logging or stack trace in the `_command` function.

However, all of these are unrelated to the Hack features not working for you.

I recommend trying to build Nuclide from source by:

`git clone git@github.com:facebook/nuclide.git ~/nuclide && cd ~/nuclide && ./scripts/dev/setup`

Then, use `/home/$USER/pkg/nuclide/server/nuclide-start-server` as the remote server command.

Finally, the contents of log files: `~/nuclide.nohup.out` and `/tmp/nuclide-logs/nuclide.log` on your client and server could help you understand what's going on.

Comment: You saved my day :) I have updated my question and i will update it later if i find out why watchman does not monitor files. Thanks!